# Windows 8 Visual Studio 2012 debugger issue

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have been developing apps on windows8 for a month and yesterday all of the sudden debugger stopped working. System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine leaves nothing on output windows, Visual Studio is not even reacting (of course after clicking on item) for something like this:

```
    private void Button_PointerPressed_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Please help me. Re-installing Visual Studio didn't help me (after re-installing VS have some data still in its memory :/ recent projects etc. maybe there is a way to full uninstall VS?)
Outpout windows only shows things like this:

```
 'xyz.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded ...
```

SyntaxError

Comment: +1 I have the same issue and can't figure out why.  Brand new projects that I create won't automatically attach the debugger and allow me to use things like Javascript Console or DOM Explorer

Comment: Do you use Windows8 latest version (rtm or smth) and latest Visual Studio? I had reinstall whole OS to deal with that issue... (it was installation only for developing purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently install the Office 2013 Preview?  If so, that may cause Visual Studio 2012 RC to break.  Download this for the fix: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30178 (and see also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2703187).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i didn't installed Office 2013. I have installed this update for VS